# selective hydrolysis problem

Tags: reaction-mechanism, esters

I am aware that esters can be selectively hydrolysed depending on the type of alkyl group present e.g. Me ester vs t-butyl ester, the latter is reactive to acidic conditions and not basic because of its inability to form tetrahedral intermediate. But what reagent could I use to carry out the following transformation?

[image]

I see it is the O-C bond that breaks, so it is acyl cleavage (Ac). Acidic conditions would destroy my Me ester as would basic, so how can I get around this? Could a big bulky base, say LDA, take it down a B(Ac)2 route (generate CO2?)

Answer (score 5):

If you use methanol as a solvent and add a suitable base, you should end up with the correct product, since any MeOH attacking the protecting group you want to keep will simply re-form the methyl ester, whereas the acetate will cleave to give the unprotected alcohol.

You could potentially also achieve this using sodium methoxide/methanol to speed the reaction up, but standard potassium carbonate/methanol is usually just fine.

[image]

Comment: this makes sense as it would reversibly add/leave. how does cleavage take place mechanistically? Is it attack of methanol at the carbonyl then leaving group is the "rest of the ester"

Comment: Pretty much. Standard addition elimination mechanism

Answer (score 2):

You could try refluxing in NaOMe/MeOH. The presence of methanol would preserve the methyl ester, while transesterification would produce methyl acetate as a by-product.